how to create multiple select parameter in tableau & combine columns
The dataset I use is like this
raw data
for example in a column balloon
The number 1 in the balloon column indicates that the warehouse has balloons, and 0 indicates that the warehouse does not have balloons.
I use this calculated field with IF ELSE logic, but the output is not what I want
IF [Balloon] =1 THEN 'Balloon'
ELSEIF  [Peach] =1 THEN 'Peach'
ELSEIF  [Pasta] =1 THEN 'Pasta'
ELSE ''
END

output using that calculated filed
The expected output is that I can select multiple select with a list of Balloon, Peach, and Pasta (only these three).
if I select the Balloon, peach, and paste filters/parameters, then the total WH is 453.
if I choose the Balloon filter, then the result is 812.
if I filter pasta, then 12.
if I filter peach, then 29.
if I filter pasta and peach, then 30.
if I filter Balloon and pasta, then 140.
if I filter balloon and peach, then 246.
example expected multiple select parameter
multiple select parameter

They way your data is currently set up, you cannot split your hard coded [total WH] value, only return it. Your calc field would need to include cases for each permutation of balloon, peach and pasta as shown in your first picture to get the output you're expecting.

Read about sets in Tableau
